# How do I create "profiles" in an android app?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, element

I'm fairly inexperienced with programming and haven't done much outside of school.  To sharpen my skills I've been teaching myself how to develop an android application using the courses on Udacity.  One of the assignments is to create a "tour guide" app for which I decided that on top of having listview's for the different categories I would like to have each item open into it's own profile (i.e. when I press a restaurant under the restaurant page it goes to the profile activity with the elements being specifically for the one I selected).  While I get how to use the adapter and Arraylist for a listview, I am unsure how to apply to this concept when you only want to have 1 item populate the activity at a time.  Thoughts?

Comment: Well when you click on an item in the arraylist, you get a reference say name of the restaurant, this you need to pass in an intent as an extra while launching the profile activity, in the profile activity, get this name using (getStringExtra method) and then you can fetch the details of restaurant from database or server using the name.... Or pass the entire details of the restaurant via object to the intent.

Comment: Thank you! I guess the answer ended up being pretty simple but you got me on the right track!